# Change a link to nofollow using add_filter in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add nofollow to the Venue links in my event calendar. See a sample page https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/events/event/kona-brewers-festival/

The function I am using is below. I am getting an error when I place it in my functions.php

I would appreciate any tips and help how to fix this.

```
add_filter('tribe_get_event_website_link', 'ip_nofollow_link', 10, 2);

function ip_nofollow_link($html)  {
return str_replace('<a href="%s" target="%s">%s</a>,' '<a href="%s" target="%s">%s</a> rel="nofollow"', $html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your site already uses SEO Yoast, I suggest you use that feature to add the nofollow options. It would be much safer then working it around via functions. And this is for an on page SEO optimization not a function.

Here is all explained [Robots Meta Tags](https://yoast.com/robots-meta-tags/)

• If you’re linking to pass value to your users, you’re probably okay keeping the links followed.
• If you’re linking to a site that is largely unrelated to your originating site, you should probably nofollow the link.
• If you’re linking for SEO value above and beyond the value to your users, don’t. Nofollow the link or don’t link at all.
• If your interlinking reaches a level where you’re connecting 50+ sites together, nofollow your links, even if they pass user value.

Also check [Nofollow from Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nofollow)